# Convert sentence or camelCase word to spinal-case

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to convert both sentence case and camel case to spinal case.

I am able to change camel case to by adding a space before every capital letter, but when I apply it to sentences with capital letters after spaces, I get extra spacing.

Here is my function so far :

```
function spinalCase(str) {
    var noCamel = str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1');
    var newStr = noCamel.replace(/\s|_/g, "-");
    return newStr.toLowerCase();
}

spinalCase("makeThisSpinal"); //returns make-this-spinal
spinalCase("Make This Spinal"); //returns -make--this--spinal
```

Comment: Can you highlight some more examples of what you want this function to do? I got confused looking at the second example as something you wanted, instead of something that you're trying to avoid.

Comment: You can use instead of your var newStr, with this - var newStr = noCamel.replace(/\s+|_+/g, "-"); it will elimenate extra spaces, but you have to think about "special cases" like capital letter in first word

Answer (score 2):

Get lodash, specifically, https://lodash.com/docs#kebabCase.

```
_.kebabCase('makeThisSpinal') // make-this-spinal
_.kebabCase('Even Sentences Work') // even-sentences-work
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
var noCamel = str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1');
```

Try:

```
var noCamel = str.replace(/(\B[A-Z])/g, ' $1');
```

Comment: For reference for the OP: \B "Matches a zero-width non-word boundary, such as between two letters or between two spaces." See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're replacing all capital letters with a space and its lowercase letter. So in your sentence, you're getting two spaces before `this` and `spinal`.

What you can do is replace all uppercase letters with `"-$1"` and then just remove all spaces from the string.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function spinalCase(str) {
    var noCamel = str.replace(/([a-z](?=[A-Z]))/g, '$1 ')
    var newStr = noCamel.replace(/\s|_/g, "-");
    return newStr.toLowerCase();
}

spinalCase("makeThisSpinal"); //returns make-this-spinal
spinalCase("Make This Spinal"); //returns -make-this-spinal
```

Instead of `str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1')` for the camel case split, you should use `str.replace(/([a-z](?=[A-Z]))/g, '$1 ')` which will space out each word regardless of case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, perhaps you will find it good reference:

```
function spinalCase(str) {
  var newStr = str[0];

  for (var j = 1; j < str.length; j++) {
    // if not a letter make a dash
    if (str[j].search(/\W/) !== -1 || str[j] === "_") {
      newStr += "-";
    }
    // if a Capital letter is found 
    else if (str[j] === str[j].toUpperCase()) {
      // and preceded by a letter or '_'
      if (str[j-1].search(/\w/) !== -1 && str[j-1] !== "_") {
        // insert '-' and carry on
        newStr += "-";
        newStr += str[j];
      }
      else {
        newStr += str[j];
      }
    }
    else {
        newStr += str[j];
    }
  }

  newStr = newStr.toLowerCase();
  return newStr;
}
```